# How to randomly select content to display with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, random

I have a banner in a sidebar that is displayed by a chunk of HTML, in my Ruby on Rails application in my `views/home/index.html` But I have another banner. I want to randomly display one of these, every time someone views the page.

```
<section id="audio-banner">
<a onclick="changeClass("#swap") href="#">
<img src="someImage.gif" >
</a>
</section>
```

and

```
<section id="audio-banner">
<a onclick="changeClass("#swap2") href="#">
<img src="someOtherImage.gif" >
</a>
</section>
```

I am new to Ruby and Rails. I'm not sure where to put the predefined HTML (model, controller, helper, etc.) or how to write the function that will display one of these two randomly.

I started out by editing `helpers/home_helper.rb` and inserted the following code

```
module StoreHelper
  def randomAudio
    audio1 = '<section id="audio-banner">'
    audio1 << '<a onclick="changeClass("#swap"); return false;" href="#">'
    audio1 << '<img src="some.gif">'
    audio1 << '</a>'
    audio1 << '</section>'
    audio1
    audio2 = '<section id="audio-banner">'
    audio2 << '<a onclick="changeClass("#swap2"); return false;" href="#">'
    audio2 << '<img src="someOther.gif" alt="Estate">'
    audio2 << '</a>'
    audio2 << '</section>'
    audio2
  end
end
```

But that's as far as I got, because I know it isn't correct. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an improved version of your code (should work). Note that in real app, you should move these HTML parts to partials. But here, for the sake of simplicity, let's leave them inline.

```
module StoreHelper
  def randomAudio
    audio1 = <<-HTML
    <section id="audio-banner">
      <a onclick="changeClass("#swap"); return false;" href="#">
        <img src="some.gif">
      </a>
    '</section>
    HTML

    audio2 = <<-HTML
    <section id="audio-banner">
      <a onclick="changeClass("#swap2"); return false;" href="#">
        <img src="someOther.gif" alt="Estate">
      </a>
    </section>
   HTML

   # pick one of them randomly
   [audio1, audio2].sample
  end
end
```

It uses [heredocs](http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/12/ruby-multiline-strings-here-doc-or.html) to define HTML snippets without extra noise. Also read about [Array#sample](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-sample).

Comment: This is really not a good example. **Helpers shouldn't contain HTML**.

Comment: +1 @JakubArnold. In that sample, the HTML should be moved to files and referenced more like `['path/to/audio1', 'path/to/audio2'].sample` and then that path be passed to the template/view. But that's icing on the cake. The example was simply showing the concept.

Comment: @theTinMan: exactly. Just showing the concept. Maybe the OP doesn't even know about partials. Better to introduce things slowly :)

Comment: Agreed. Not knowing how to randomize using `sample` was a hint.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev While that is true, this won't serve as a good reference for other people who come to SO, and expect everything what they read to be the correct way of doing things.

Comment: @JakubArnold: I added a note about that being not a good practice.

Answer (score 4):

Putting plain HTML to a helper doesn't seem right to me. I would probably create 2 partials: `shared/_audio1.html.erb` and `shared/_audio2.html.erb` given you might want to display these banners on different pages in the future. Now all you need to do is randomly render this partial:

```
= render "shared/%s.html.erb" % ["audio1", "audio2"].sample
```

The partial's names are hardcoded but it should get you going.

Answer (score -2):

Don't bother with partials or with helpers.

In your `home_controller`, set up an array of the possible images. If you want to generate it from a folder then use:

```
# Loads from public directory and subsequently removes public from the path
# so that you can use it as your image URI.
@images = Dir.glob("public/banner-images/*.gif").map{|i| i.gsub(/^public/, "") }
```

Then in your `views/home/index.html.erb`:

```
<%= image_tag @images.select %>
```

Simples.

Comment: These are wrong: `'public'.gsub(/^[public]*/, "") => ""` vs. `'club'.gsub(/^[public]*/, "") => ""`. This would be right: `'public'.sub(/^public/, '') => ""` vs. `'club'.sub(/^public/, '') => "club"`. If you're trying to create a path then use `'public/'.sub(%r[^public/], '') => ""` or `'public/path'.sub(%r[^public/], '') => "path"`

Comment: my apologies, it didn't want the `[]`. didn't spot it because it would in actual fact work, because if you used what I put above then all the strings would have to start in "public", but none-the-less, answer updated. I don't think a mistake like that warrants a downvote, personally.

Comment: It's a good idea to put actual output of your code into your answer. You'll catch problems like this. "Mistake" or "bug", both are the same in an answer, and, when they keep the solution from working they warrant a downvote because they're incorrect.

Comment: They didn't keep the solution from working, sir, hence I didn't spot it.